# How can I get git difftool side-by-side diff to show filenames?

Tags: git, filenames, difftool

I've got a really nice side-by-side difftool command:

```
git difftool -y -x "diff --suppress-common-lines -b -y -W 225"
```

and all it's lacking is filenames. What switches do I need to add, to make the filenames appear? I don't care where they appear (above, by the side or below), as long as they're contextual to the changes.

Comment: Maybe, to use a different difftool, like explained [here](http://www.gitshah.com/2010/12/how-to-setup-kdiff-as-diff-tool-for-git.html) ?

Comment: Thanks, I've got a GUI tool that I can use, but I'm after a console-only solution